# To get a Triangle Shaped Background for TextView

Tags: android, background, textview, drawable

I'm trying to fix a triangle shaped background for a TextView as shown [image: below].

I'm using the following XML code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/type_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle_bg"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="Sponsors"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Here's the code for triangle_bg.xml

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="90%"
        android:pivotY="-50%"
        android:toDegrees="-45" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <solid android:color="#00C6FF" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

the resultant image in my xml using the above code looks as [image: below]

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve the triangle background as shown in my first background..??
Thanks in Advance

I've an idea of placing an Image instead of using a textview. But I would like to know whether there is any option to use textview. Please help if any!!!

Comment: read `Drawable` documentation and learn how to create a custom `Drawable` class

Comment: Instead of textview you can place the image in it having text Sponcers

Comment: This link might be of your interest [Android triangle (arrow) defined as an XML shape](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a custom drawable like the following:

```
public class TriangleDrawable extends Drawable {

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight());
        path.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

Set this as the background of your `TextView`

```
findViewById(R.id.text).setBackground(new TriangleDrawable());
```

and be sure to apply padding to left / right, since the drawable will only draw within the bounds of the `TextView`.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingRight="32dp"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:id="@+id/text"/>
```

Comment: very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

use an image with text sponsors as, you can't change the angles between two side in a rectangle in xml